# Jquery centering div on page and chopping off the top

Tags: jquery, function

I am using the following Jquery script to center the container div in the middle of the window. The problem comes when the user has a resolution that is smaller than the container, as when the site loads the top of the div is chopped off. How can I set the function only to trigger if the browser size or resolution is bigger than the container div ?.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var positionContent = function () {
            var width = $(window).width(); // the window width
            var height = $(window).height(); // the window height
            var containerwidth = $('.container').outerWidth(); // the container div width
            var containerheight = $('.container').outerHeight(); // the container div height
            $('.container').css({position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight())/2 }); 
        };
        //Call this when the window first loads
        $(document).ready(positionContent);
        //Call this whenever the window resizes.
        $(window).bind('resize', positionContent);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You've already got the values you need, just check if winHeight < containerHeight, and the same for the widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the window dimensions to the container dimensions, and if the container is taller/wider than the window, set the top/left position to 0:

```
$('.container').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: width > containerwidth ? (width - containerwidth) / 2 : 0,
    top: height > containerheight ? (height - containerheight) / 2 : 0
});
```

BTW, you had already defined `width`, `height`, `containerwidth`, and `containerheight`, so I'm not sure why you didn't reuse them in your code.

Comment: Thanks ! that's sorted it :)